# I have pylance installed on Vscode but I keep getting a 'module could not be resolved' error. What could be the issue?

Tags: python, windows, module, pylance

So, I have already checked and I already have pylance installed. I also did a pip install, same thing. A lot of imports don't work and get 'module could not be resolved' or something of that nature

I have tried pip install. Shooting in the dark I guess. Maybe it's a path issue but I want to know what others think.

Answer (score -1):

I understand that pip is for older Python, pip3 for Python3+  Most stuff I've been using lately uses Python 3.9.  Maybe try using "pip3 install..." instead?